# How to reduce struct value in Presto?

Tags: sql, data-structures, reduce, presto

I have a column, 'mystruct', formatted as `struct<key1:struct<id:bigint,name:string>,key2:double,key3:double>`. I want so sum all of the values affiliated with key3 (so in the example below, I would want my final result to be 812.158. Because everything is a nested struct, trying to CROSS_JOIN_UNNEST(mystruct) AS t(stuff) doesn't work.

```
{
  "stuff1": {
    "key1": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": ""
    },
    "key2": 1,
    "key3": 185.000
  },
  "stuff2": {
    "key1": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": ""
    },
    "key2": 0.1581,
    "key3": 627.158
  },
  "stuff3": {
    "key1": {
      "id": 0,
      "name": ""
    },
    "key2": 1,
    "key3": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please share some [mre] including the data? Or at least the result of `select * from table limit 1`?

Comment: Also I would guess that something like `select sum(mystruct.key3) from table group by true` should do the trick.